# Python-asyncio - using timers/threading to terminate async

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, aiortc

I have an async coroutine that I want to terminate using a timer/thread. The coroutine is based of [this example](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/videostream-cli/cli.py) from aiortc.

```py
args = parse_args()
client = Client(connection, media, args.role)

# run event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    timer = None
    if args.timeout:
        print("Timer started")
        timer = threading.Timer(args.timeout, loop.run_until_complete, args=(client.close(),))
        timer.start()

    loop.run_until_complete(client.run())

    if timer:
        timer.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    # cleanup
    loop.run_until_complete(client.close())
```

This does not work and raises `RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')`

Why does this raise the error? My guess is that it's because the loop is running on a different thread. However, creating a new loop doesn't work as it gets a future attached to a different loop.

```py
def timer_callback():
    new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    new_loop.run_until_complete(client.close())
```

Following that, how can I use a timer to end the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Following that, how can I use a timer to end the script?

You can call [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit a coroutine to an event loop running in another thread:

```
    if args.timeout:
        print("Timer started")
        timer = threading.Timer(
            args.timeout,
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe,
            args=(client.close(), loop),
        )
        timer.start()
```

Note, however, that since you're working with asyncio, you don't need a dedicated thread for the timer, you could just create a coroutine and tell it to wait before doing something:

```
    if args.timeout:
        print("Timer started")
        async def close_after_timeout(): 
            await asyncio.sleep(args.timeout)
            await client.close()
        loop.create_task(close_after_timeout())
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the general solution that I was looking for, I added a `timeout` variable to the client constructor, and within `client.run()` I added `asyncio.sleep(timeout)` which would exit the loop. This is enough for my purposes.